# Setting up MySql Sharding or circumventing it

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, sharding

I am working with a pre-existing bash file to set up a series of databases for a open source data server (Zotero) and I am running into a mysql structure I am not familiar with:

```
MASTER="mysql -h localhost -P 3307 -u root -pSomePassword"
SHARD="mysql -h localhost -P 3308 -u root -pSomePassword"
ID1="mysql -h localhost -P 3309 -u root -pSomePassword"
ID2="mysql -h localhost -P 3310 -u root -pSomePassword"
WWW="mysql -h localhost -P 3311 -u root -pSomePassword"
CACHE="mysql -h localhost -P 3312 -u root -pSomePassword"

echo "CREATE DATABASE zoterotest_master" | $MASTER
echo "CREATE DATABASE zoterotest_master" | $SHARD
echo "CREATE DATABASE zoterotest1" | $SHARD
echo "CREATE DATABASE zoterotest2" | $SHARD
echo "CREATE DATABASE zoterotest_ids" | $ID1
echo "CREATE DATABASE zoterotest_ids" | $ID2
```

It appears there are multiple instances of MySql for some sort of Shard/cluster design but when I look at the db configuration in the php code I see it's connecting to the same port... Now I am confused.

```
function DBConnectAuth($db) {
    if ($db == 'master') {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $port = 3306;
        $db = 'master';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = 'SomePassword';
    }
    else if ($db == 'shard') {
        $host = false;
        $port = false;
        $db = false;
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = 'SomePassword';
    }
    else if ($db == 'id1') {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $port = 3306;
        $db = 'ids';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = 'SomePassword';
    }

    else if ($db == 'id2') {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $port = 3306;
        $db = 'ids';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = 'SomePassword';
    }

    else if ($db == 'www1') {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $port = 3306;
        $db = 'www';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = 'SomePassword';
    }

    else if ($db == 'www2') {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $port = 3306;
        $db = 'www';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = 'SomePassword';
    }

    else if ($db == 'cache') {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $port = 3306;
        $db = 'cache';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = 'SomePassword';
    }

    else {
        throw new Exception("Invalid db '$db'");
    }
    return array('host'=>$host, 'port'=>$port, 'db'=>$db, 'user'=>$user, 'pass'=>$pass);
}
```

My question is, does this look like a typical Shard design? And how do I set it up in MySql - do I just spin up multiple instances on the the ports specified in the Bash or do I have to do something special?

I am tempted to just point everything in the Bash file to 3306 and update the DB shard tables to point to 3306 as well but I have a feeling it isn't that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharding on a single server makes very little sense.  Sharding is usually done by having the *same* databases on *similar* servers, containing *subsets* of the data.  Sharding provides scaling beyond what you can get from replication, clustering, etc.

Take, for example, a photo-sharing site with millions of users and billions of photos.  That won't fit on a single server, but by splitting up the users, together with their photos.  Small ancillary tables would either be copied or accessed on some non-sharded server/database.

Perhaps we disagree on the definition of "shard"?  In which case, please explain what you mean by it.